Implementing Vector Multiplication with Scalars in Python
For a couple of hours I've been trying to figure it out. How to write the multiplication or division of the vector in mul method by scalar value?
class Vector2D:
def __init__(self, x: float | int, y: float | int):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    pass

def __mul__(self, other: float | int) -> 'Vector2D':
        if not isinstance(other, Vector2D):
            raise ValueError("IncorrectType")
        return Vector2D(self.x * other,self.y * other)
        pass

def __truediv__(self, other: float | int) -> 'Vector2D':
        if not isinstance(other, Vector2D):
            raise ValueError("IncorrectType")
        self.x=self.x/other
        self.y=self.y/other
        return Vector2D(self.x,self.y)
        pass


    class Test04(unittest.TestCase):
def test_multiply(self):
        p1 = Vector2D(1, 2)

        mult = p1 * 5

        self.assertTrue(mult == Vector2D(5, 10))

        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            mult = p1 * 'Alice'

def test_divide(self):
        p1 = Vector2D(5, 10)

        mult = p1 / 5

        self.assertTrue(mult == Vector2D(1, 2))

        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            mult = p1 / 'Alice'


test(Test04)

I still get the message:

Blockquote
line 113, in test_divide
mult = p1 / 5

, line 49, in truediv
raise ValueError("IncorrectType")
ValueError: IncorrectType

Blockquote
line 92, in test_multiply
mult = p1 * 5

, line 34, in mul
raise ValueError("IncorrectType")
ValueError: IncorrectType

Your instance check only allows values of type Vector2D, but you are passing floats and ints; you need to relax this check by adding more types or removing it.

I see but this check should be working anyway. I'd like to make some changes in
"def mul(self, other"

The check will not work if the value other is of type float/int, which is what you're passing. Change the error to ValueError("Incorrect type: {}".format(type(other))) to see what I mean.
